# Closed form for $B(1-z\omega,1-z\omega^2)$ where $B(z_1,z_2)$ is the Beta function and $\omega$ is a cube root of unity

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis, beta-function

> I am looking for a *closed form* for $$B(1-z\omega,1-z\omega^2)$$ where $B(z_1,z_2)$ is the Beta function, $\omega$ is a cube root of unity and $\Re( 1-z\omega )>0$, $\Re( 1-z\omega^2 )>0$

I tried as follows: We know that if $\omega$ is a cube root of unity then $\omega^3=1$ and $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$

By definition of the Beta function $$B(1-z\omega,1-z\omega^2)=\int_{0}^{1} x^{-z\omega}(1-x)^{-z\omega^2} dx $$
So we can write using $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$
$$B(1-z\omega,1-z\omega^2)=\int_{0}^{1} x^{-z\omega}(1-x)^{z(1+\omega)} dx $$
So we get $$B(1-z\omega,1-z\omega^2)=\int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^{z}\left(\frac{1-x}{x}\right)^{z\omega} dx $$
Any help would definitely be appreciated. Thank you!